# Perl: How to get the link target of a soundcloud feed mp3

Tags: perl, soundcloud, lwp

I would like to retrieve the mp3 link target of an mp3 in a soundcloud feed in perl, for example the ultimate location of this podcast url: http://feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/176971524-thetalkshow-thetalkshow-100.mp3

If I try to stream it resolves into a comlex http://ec-media.soundcloud.com/.... address.

Is there any possibility to get this resolved ec-media.soundcloud address in Perl?

I've already tried the following code, but without success

```
use LWP::UserAgent qw();
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $ua->get('http://feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/176971524-thetalkshow-thetalkshow-100.mp3');
print $response->request->uri . "\n";
```

Comment: The URL to get the file itself is likely being generated dynamically by soundcloud, and may not work consistently even if you are able to extract it.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the mp3 file with LWP::Simple:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
my $url = "http://feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/176971524-thetalkshow-thetalkshow-100.mp3";
getstore($url, "my-file-name.mp3");
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to download it but only get the ultimate file address

Comment: Where are you looking for that URL?

Answer (score 0):

You mean get the 301 or 302 redirect address. Just disable auto redirect.

```
use LWP::UserAgent qw();
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->max_redirect(0); # disable auto redirect
my $response = $ua->get('http://feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/176971524-thetalkshow-thetalkshow-100.mp3');
print "new location: " . $response->header('Location');
```

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem. However, I had to change in the third line the max_redirect from 0 to 1. If you change this in your answer I will immediately mark it as answer.

Comment: @Andy I'm just curious, where does the first redirect go to?

Comment: Sometimes we don't know how many redirects the url will made, usually you should write a loop until no redirect(301,302 with Location header) response return, then final url gotten.

Comment: And a special defined response handler should be provided to get the response status and header only, NOT read body to prevent download real file in the last url reading.